# Attempting to implement a service that would find objects (i.e. parts of a license plate) and then scan them through OCR (OCR already implemented.)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The goal of my application is to scan a license plate and return **only** the license plate number. No state or state code, no extra text at the bottom (Virginia is for lovers etc). [image]

I am using MLKit's FireBase as my OCR engine. Currently, the OCR reader attempts to read both the Virginia and the license plate number that I have written. The OCR is decently old, that is why the Virginia (which is too small for it to properly read) is translated wrong, but that part isn't relevant.
My final goal is to have only the license plate number appear in the text area

I have included relevant code files below

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mvsolutions.snap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.mvsolutions.snap.ui.home;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextDetector;
import com.mvsolutions.snap.R;

import java.util.List;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button captureImageButton, detectButton;
    private Bitmap imageBitmap;
    private TextView capturedTextView;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        imageView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_image_view_img);
        capturedTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_text_view_txt);
        captureImageButton = root.findViewById(R.id.button_capture_image_btn);
        detectButton = root.findViewById(R.id.button_detect_text_btn);


        captureImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
        detectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                detectTextFromImage();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    private void placeholder() {
         //ignore this
    }

    private void detectTextFromImage() {

        capturedTextView.setText("");
        FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);
        FirebaseVisionTextDetector visionTextDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionTextDetector();
        visionTextDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                List<FirebaseVisionText.Block> textBlocks = firebaseVisionText.getBlocks();
                if(textBlocks.size() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Text Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    for(FirebaseVisionText.Block block : textBlocks){
                        String text = block.getText();
                        capturedTextView.setText(capturedTextView.getText() + " " + text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any solutions for me besides using a newer version of FireBase?

Comment: Maybe use the BoundingBox of the text `Block` and filter out all but the largest height blocks.  On the assumption that the license portion is significantly taller than any other text.  All measurements would be relative since you can't assume distance to object.  How many blocks are returned in your posted example; if its all one block then this approach fails.

Comment: @Andy How should I do this? Is this something that is already implemented? Do I have to implement a new API or SDK  or such?

Comment: The `block` (in the `textBlocks` loop) has a method called `getBoundingBox` - log these values for a better understanding of what you can do with it.  (If it's all one block then the only alternative I can think of is pattern matching to filter - but vanity plates always throw a wrench in this kind of thing.)

Comment: Do you know of any easy ways that I can change my code to make it so that the strings are loaded as separate blocks? Currently I have it set so they are one block.

Comment: Not without implementing your own processImage.  It also appears you are using an older version of ml.vision.text - because a later version uses `getTextBlocks` and in that version a `block` is a `TextBlock` and  has a method `getLines()` which may be helpful to distinguish between portions of plate.

Comment: Do you know what version this starts at? I am using an older version because the newer versions are all over the cloud and cost money.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit - they recently split the on-device version from the cloud version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217326/discussion-between-agoraya0710-and-andy).